# C# Cannot overload + if second parameter is an enum

Tags: c#, enums, mono, operator-overloading

I have the following signature for overloaded `+`:

```cs
    public static double operator +(MyClass x, MyEnum e)
```

and an expression of the form:

```cs
    x.Value = someMyClassValue + MyEnum.X;
```

The behavior the debugger shows is as if the expression had been:

```cs
    x.Value = MyEnum.X;
```

The overload never gets called.

I also have:

```
    public static double operator +(MyClass x, object o)
```

but that doesn't get called either for enums, though it does for other cases.

I also have overloads for string, int, float, double, and they all work perfectly. Why is enum a special case, and why the odd behavior? Could this be a bug in the Mono compiler?

I'm using Mono 2.10.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.04.

**Afternote**

The problem was that I had also defined an implicit cast to `int`. See my answer for details.

Comment: Works fine in Linqpad.

Comment: No repo.  I wrote a simple program and ran it (not on mono) and it worked as expected.  Either there's a bug in some of the code you haven't shown, you're not properly observing the result, or it's indeed a mono bug.

Comment: May be because enums can be declared as different types.  In VB, e.g., you can declare an enum as a byte, integer, short, long, etc.  The compiler wouldn't know what type to expect from the enum.

Comment: @ps2goat: That won't make any difference.

Comment: @ps2goat Note that the operand isn't `Enum`, meaning any enum, it's a specific enum type.  In any case, even if it was `Enum`, that still wouldn't matter.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using either Mono 2.10.8.1 or Mono 3.0.10 (on a Mac, though, not Ubuntu). The compiler seems to generate the correct code (verified by monodis) and the result is as expected.

Comment: I too wrote a small example, and it worked. I'll add the complications of my case to it until it breaks, and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had also defined:

```
public static implicit operator int(MyClass o)
```

The implicit cast takes precedence over the overloaded operator, and the whole addition expression takes the type of the enum.

Since I wanted to keep the implicit cast to `int`, I adopted this solution:

```
    public enum MyEnum : ulong
```

With that, the cast to `int` no longer takes place.

The following program demonstrates the problem I was having. It's output is "SECOND" instead of "OK".

```
using System;

public class EnumPlus
{
    public enum Constant
    {
        FIRST,
        SECOND
    };

    // if this implicit cast is removed the result is what I expected
    public static implicit operator int(EnumPlus f)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public static string operator+(EnumPlus o, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("operator + called for int");
        return "BAD";
    }

    public static string operator+(EnumPlus o, Constant Constant)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("operator + called for enum");
        return "OK";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        EnumPlus o = new EnumPlus();
        Console.WriteLine(o + Constant.FIRST);
    }

}
```